# user_email по first_name в плагине All Import Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, xml, users

Есть xml, который импортируется с помощью all import WordPress. Там есть тег
`<SupplyRecipient>Имя пользователя</SupplyRecipient>`. Имя пользователя совпадает с first_name. Нужно получить user_email
Пробовала:

```
function emailshop($SupplyRecipient) {
global $wpdb;
  $users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
  WHERE meta_key = 'first_name' AND meta_value = 'Имя пользователя'" 
  );
 if( $users ) {
 foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        $esh1=$user->user_id;
        $user = get_userdata( $esh1 );
        $esh = $user->user_email;
        return $esh;
} 
} 
}
?>
```

Это работает, но мне надо meta_value = 'Имя пользователя' заменить на переменную, например так: meta_value =  $SupplyRecipient. Подскжите, пожалуйста как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вот так заработало:

```
function emailshop($SupplyRecipient) {
  global $wpdb;
  $users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE 
  meta_key = 'first_name' AND meta_value = '".$wpdb- 
  >escape($SupplyRecipient)."'" );
  if( $users ) {
     foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        $esh1=$user->user_id;
        $user = get_userdata( $esh1 );
        $esh = $user->user_email;
        return $esh;
   } 
   } 
   }
    ?>
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).